# Synchronization of multiple processes running with 'while True' loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I need the following:

- Main function trains a model.
- At every epoch, its parameters are copied to a test model.
- The test model is used for testing on multiple datasets.
- Testing must happen in parallel while training continue for the next epoch.
- Wait for testing to be done on all datasets before moving on to the next training epoch.
- Testing function reports some stats, that are read by the main function.

The following code uses a single `Queue` and tests only the first dataset. I need to extend it for all datasets.

```
import signal
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

STOP = -1

data = {'x': np.random.rand(), 'y': np.random.rand(), 'z': np.random.rand()}

def initializer():
    """Ignore CTRL+C in the worker process."""
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)


def online_test(p2c_queue, c2p_queue, data_id, model, shared_stats):
    print(f'testing function for {data_id} has started')
    while True: # keep process alive for testing
        print(f'... {data_id} waiting ...')
        epoch = p2c_queue.get()
        if epoch == STOP:
            print(f'... testing {data_id} is over, function is ending ...')
            break
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']}})
        print(f'... {data_id} evaluation ...')
        pred = model.value
        err = pred - data[data_id] # simplified version, the real one takes some time
        # shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': pred, 'error': err}})
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': epoch, 'error': -epoch}}) # to debug if order of calls is correct
        c2p_queue.put(True) # notify parent that testing is done for requested epoch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = {**{'epoch': []},
             **{data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']} for data_id in data.keys()}}
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    p2c_queue = manager.Queue() # parent-to-child: parent tells child to start testing
    c2p_queue = manager.Queue() # child-to-parent: child tells parent that testing is done
    test_model = manager.Value('d', 10.0)
    shared_stats = manager.dict()
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=initializer)
    p2c_queue.put(0) # testing can start for raw model
    pool.apply_async(online_test,
        args=(p2c_queue, c2p_queue, 'x', test_model, shared_stats))

    try: # wrap all in a try-except to handle KeyboardInterrupt
        for epoch in range(10):
            print('training epoch', epoch)
            # ... here I do some training and then copy my parameters to test_model
            test_model.value = np.random.rand() # simplified version
            print('... waiting for testing before moving on to next epoch ...')
            if c2p_queue.get(): # keep training only if previous eval is done
                print(f'... epoch {epoch} testing is done, stats are')
                for data_id in shared_stats.keys(): # but first copy stats here
                    for k in stats[data_id].keys():
                        mu = np.mean(shared_stats[data_id][k])
                        stats[data_id][k].append(mu)
                        print('  ', data_id, k, mu)
                p2c_queue.put(epoch + 1)

        p2c_queue.put(STOP)
        print(stats)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    else:
        pool.close()

    pool.join()
```

1. How to I synch multiple processes? The example here spawns only one for data `'x'`. I tried:

- Using multiple queues but my code hangs. Each queue is supposed to have only one item corresponding to the testing dataset.
- Using one queue. The queue is supposed to have as many items as the number of testing datasets. The idea is to check when the queue is empty, but I have read that `empty()` is unreliable.

2. Do I need a lock? `shared_stats` is accessed by all processes, possibly at the same time, but each sets only a specific key of the dictionary, so it should not be a problem. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `JoinableQueue`, code is below.

However, this version does testing differently from how I originally planned.
Here any process can be in charge of testing any dataset, while I would like to have one process testing **always the same dataset**. Any suggestion/comment is more than welcome.

```
import signal
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

STOP = 'STOP'

data = {'x': np.random.rand(), 'y': np.random.rand(), 'z': np.random.rand()}
debug_value = {'x': 1, 'y': 10, 'z': 100}

def initializer():
    """Ignore CTRL+C in the worker process."""
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)


def online_test(queue, model, shared_stats):
    while True: # keep process alive for testing
        epoch, data_id = queue.get()
        if data_id == STOP:
            print(f'... test function is stopping ...')
            break
        print(f'testing function for {data_id} has started for epoch {epoch}')
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']}})
        # print(f'... evaluation ...')
        pred = model.value
        err = pred - data[data_id] # simplified version, the real one takes some time
        checker = debug_value[data_id]
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': epoch * checker, 'error': - epoch * checker}}) # to debug if order of calls is correct
        # shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': pred, 'error': err}})
        queue.task_done() # notify parent that testing is done for requested epoch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = {**{'epoch': []},
             **{data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']} for data_id in data.keys()}}
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    test_model = manager.Value('d', 10.0)
    shared_stats = manager.dict()
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=initializer)
    for data_id in data.keys():
        pool.apply_async(online_test,
            args=(test_queue, test_model, shared_stats))
        test_queue.put((0, data_id)) # testing can start

    try: # wrap all in a try-except to handle KeyboardInterrupt
        for epoch in range(10):
            print('training epoch', epoch)
            # ... here I do some training and then copy my parameters to test_model
            print('... waiting for testing before moving on to next epoch ...')
            test_queue.join() # keep training only if previous eval is done
            stats['epoch'].append(epoch + 1)
            test_model.value = np.random.rand() # simplified version
            print(f'... epoch {epoch} testing is done, stats are')
            for data_id in shared_stats.keys(): # but first copy stats here
                for k in stats[data_id].keys():
                    mu = np.mean(shared_stats[data_id][k])
                    stats[data_id][k].append(mu)
                    # print('  ', data_id, k, mu)
                test_queue.put((epoch + 1, data_id))

        for data_id in shared_stats.keys(): # notify all procs to end
            test_queue.put((-1, STOP))

        print(stats)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    else:
        pool.close()

    pool.join()
```